# Leadtools scanner source isis driver

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, leadtools-sdk

my name is Gianluca.

I have a program that takes care of scanning through LeadTools.

The problem is that I cannot recover a scanner with isis driver, while I am able to recover those with twain drivers without problems.

Now the question is ... LeadTools supports scanners with isis drivers (specifically ScanSnap IX1400 from Fujitsu)

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Ps. The version of LeadTools is 18.

Comment: According to their forum the last version of LeadTools to support ISIS scanners was 14.5 : https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t7609-

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that LEADTOOLS has discontinued support for ISIS scanning drivers for over a decade now.

More details follow:

Any version of LEADTOOLS after 14.5 did not include any support for ISIS drivers.

Older version of LEADTOOLS had support for older ISIS drivers, which were using Pixel Translations runtime (pixdfltn.dll) version number 55.1.260.832 or earlier.

In the distant past, ISIS drivers provided high-speed scanning for some high-performance scanners that was not available using traditional Twain libraries. However, LEADTOOLS developed the [Fast Twain technology](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/twain/fast-twain) that utilizes artificial intelligence to analyze a TWAIN source's capabilities to find the best combination of compression, transfer mode, and buffering scheme that provides the best possible performance for high-speed scanning.

If you already tried our Twain libraries and believe your scanner’s hardware can perform better than the results you’re getting, send full details about your scanner and what you tried to [our support team](https://www.leadtools.com/support/supportoptions).